# BeautifulSoup: Missing Schema invalid url error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download images from a web page using BeautifulSoup. I am getting the following error

```
MissingSchema: Invalid URL
```

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from os.path  import basename



url = "https://xxxxxx"

#r = requests.get(url)

request_page = urlopen(url)
page_html = request_page.read()
request_page.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')

#print(soup.title.text)
images = soup.find_all('img')
for image in images:
    name = image['alt']
    link =image['src']
    with open(name.replace(' ', '-').replace('/', '') + 'jpg', 'wb') as f:
        im = requests.get(link)
        f.write(im.content)
    

print(images)
```

I am unsure why. I know I can read the images fine because the print works fine until I aded the following code

```
with open(name.replace(' ', '-').replace('/', '') + 'jpg', 'wb') as f:
        im = requests.get(link)
        f.write(im.content)
```

I would be grateful for any help
thanks

---

EDIT

---

The url is

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Picture_of_the_day/September_2018"
```

I added the print link as requested and the output is below

```
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/Portrait_of_Tsaritsa_Natalya_Kirillovna_Naryshkina_-_Google_Cultural_Institute.jpg/300px-Portrait_of_Tsaritsa_Natalya_Kirillovna_Naryshkina_-_Google_Cultural_Institute.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Titian_-_Portrait_of_a_man_with_a_quilted_sleeve.jpg/280px-Titian_-_Portrait_of_a_man_with_a_quilted_sleeve.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/Bee_on_Lavender_Blossom_2.jpg/250px-Bee_on_Lavender_Blossom_2.jpg
```

---

edit

---

I am just wondering if it the size of the name in the link? On looking at that it seems to be buried in a lot of folders before we get to the jpeg?

Comment: after `link =image['src']`, add the line `print(link)`. Let's see what that outputs and where the error is thrown for which url

Comment: also, can you provide the url?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7752296/chitown88 I was wondering if you had a chance to look at this since the edits?

Comment: I had not. I will check it out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected based on the error, when you added that print statement you can see that the links you are trying to access are not valid urls.

`//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/Portrait_of_Tsaritsa_Natalya_Kirillovna_Naryshkina_-_Google_Cultural_Institute.jpg/300px-Portrait_of_Tsaritsa_Natalya_Kirillovna_Naryshkina_-_Google_Cultural_Institute.jpg` needs to start with `https:`.

To fix this, simply add that to the `image['src']`.

Second issue you need to fix is that when you write the file, you are writing it as `'Natalya-Naryshkinajpg'`. You need that with `jpg` as the file extesions: for example `'Natalya-Naryshkina.jpg'` I fixed that as well.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Picture_of_the_day/September_2019"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
page_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')

#print(soup.title.text)
images = soup.find_all('img')
for image in images:
    name = image['alt']
    link = 'https:' + image['src']
    #print(link)
    if 'static' not in link:
        try:
            extension = link.split('.')[-1]
            with open(name.replace(' ', '-').replace('/', '') + '.' + extension, 'wb') as f:
                im = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
                f.write(im.content)
                print(name)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    
print(images)
```

Comment: This seems to work, but the images are very small and do not open. The images come back as filename.jpg but wont open?

Comment: what url are you using?

Comment: url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Picture_of_the_day/September_2019"

Comment: I just ran it an runs just fine on my end. Not sure what the issue is for you. You could try adding in user agent in the headers. I'll add that in the code

Comment: Sorry, I am unsure what you mean by "You could try adding in user agent in the headers"

Comment: I added it in the code above

Comment: It runs fine in Google Colab, but getting an "SSLCertVerificationError " on my pc

Comment: Ok. Got 1 more idea, but will have to wait til tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully work:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'https://books.toscrape.com/'

response = requests.get(site)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]


for url in urls:
    filename = re.search(r'/([\w_-]+[.](jpg|gif|png))$', url)
    if not filename:
         print("Regex didn't match with the url: {}".format(url))
         continue
    with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
        if 'http' not in url:
            url = '{}{}'.format(site, url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me as it give an "SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool" error